# Implementing a properties edition dialog with Windows Forms

Tags: .net, winforms

With Windows Forms, I try to implement a UI to show some properties, and allow some to be edited. Properties are string key-value couples, defined when starting the dialog.

I began to implement it with horizontals FlowLayoutPanels in one big vertical FlowLayoutPanel, but the TextBoxes are not aligned:

[image]

So I tried with DataGridView, but I don't want keys to be editable, and it looks a bit awkward:

[image]

UPDATE: Tipped by SyncCircles, I tried the TableLayoutPanel, which is nicer (even though the columns are not [resizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980489/resizable-table-layout-panel-in-c-sharp)):

[image]

A very simplified version of Visual Studio's "Properties" window would be perfect.
Is there a component suited to what I am trying to accomplish?
If not, what is the usual way to do?

Comment: The PropertyGrid control is the exact match for the VS Properties window.  Just don't use a FlowLayoutPanel, use the snaplines in the designer to align controls.

Comment: Have you tried `TableLayoutPanel`? Use row and column size property to make the desired layout..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a design with `TableLayoutPanel`

[image]

Comment: Nice! Somehow when I build it it looks a bit different (see my question) Off-topic, but are columns resizable in this one?